# changing file's name of an file field when saving or editing a node

Tags: file, drupal

I'm trying to change the file name of a file uploaded as part of a node form, I'm using the file widget that comes with Drupal 8.

do you know with hook should I use?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try with `hook_file_presave();`
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/how-do-i-change-the-uploaded-file-name-after-the-node-has-been-saved